# cannot find nppi series when building dense_flow with opencv2.4.13

Tags: cmake

when building dense_flow(https://github.com/yjxiong/dense_flow),

```
OpenCV_DIR=../../../3rd-party/opencv-2.4.13/build/ cmake .. -DCUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME=OFF
```

where ../../../3rd-party/opencv-2.4.13/ is already build.

however when I do make

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable extract_cpu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppial
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppicc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppicom
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppidei
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppif
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppig
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppim
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppist
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppisu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_dep_nppitc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/extract_cpu.dir/build.make:121: recipe for target 'extract_cpu' failed
make[2]: *** [extract_cpu] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/extract_cpu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/extract_cpu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

such error comes out.
somehow I tried to link such library, however I failed to find that libraries.

Comment: You have NVidia performance libraries and CUDA installed, right?

Comment: @Kamiccolo Yes. Actually I use nvidia-docker container with CUDA9.0 and cudnn. (with Tesla v100 graphic card)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, adding the following symbolic links worked for me:

```
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppial.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppial.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppicc.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicom.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppicom.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppidei.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppidei.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppif.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppif.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppig.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppig.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppim.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppim.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppist.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppist.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppisu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppisu.so
 ln -s /usr/local/cuda-9.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppitc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dep_nppitc.so
```

Answer (score -1):

in opencv source dir:
../cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in:

```
foreach(l ${OpenCV_CUDA_LIBS_ABSPATH})
get_filename_component(_tmp "${l}" NAME_WE)
string(REGEX REPLACE "^lib" "" _tmp "${tmp}")
if(NOT TARGET "opencv_dep${tmp}") # protect against repeated inclusions
add_library("opencv_dep${tmp}" UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties("opencv_dep${_tmp}" PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${l}")
endif()
endforeach()
```

like this, comment them all,
and no need to add: set(CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME OFF)
other project link with opencv, will not have opencv_dep_npp* dependence